# Azure Network Security Group Port

Tags: azure, azure-functions

In Azure VM network security group, when we open the inbound port 443. Will it automatically open the outbound rule for the same port. Like AWS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, It will not affect the outbound port rules. They are separate rules.

By default, the outbound port rule has three rules: allowvnetoutbound, allowinternetoutbound, denyalloutbound. In fact, it has already allowed any port outgoing to the Internet or VNet. If you want to **especially** deny some ports or allow some ports **from some specific source to some specific destination**, you need to manually add some outbound rules for that ports with higher priority in your network security group. When outbound traffic matches the outbound rules, the packages will be dropped or allowed.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The NSGs in Azure are **Stateful**. Meaning that if you open an incoming port, the outgoing port will be open automatically to allow the traffic.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).